# Gmaps4Rails - custom infowindow not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I'm having trouble implementing a custom infobox on rails using the Google Maps 4 Rails gem.
I've added the infobox plugin to the top of the page and tried the code snippet in the docs, but still no custom infobox or a class of "yellow" on the infobox window.

How do I pass options for the custom infobox to the markers being generated by the following?

```
:javascript
 handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
 handler.buildMap({ provider: {
   }, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
   markers = handler.addMarkers(#{raw @hash.to_json},{builders: {Marker: InfoBoxBuilder}});
   handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
   handler.fitMapToBounds();
   handler.getMap().setZoom(9);
  });
```

I also added the following code to infowindow.js.coffee

```
class InfoBoxBuilder extends Gmaps.Google.Builders.Marker # inherit from base builder

# override method
create_infowindow: ->
  return null unless _.isString @args.infowindow
  boxText = document.createElement("div")
  boxText.setAttribute("class", 'yellow') #to customize
  boxText.innerHTML = @args.infowindow
  @infowindow = new InfoBox(@infobox(boxText))

infobox: (boxText)->
  content: boxText
  pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)
  boxStyle:
  width: "280px"

handler = Gmaps.build 'Google', { builders: { Marker: InfoBoxBuilder} }
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you misread the doc, replace:

```
:javascript
 handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
 handler.buildMap({ provider: {
   }, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
   markers = handler.addMarkers(#{raw @hash.to_json},{builders: {Marker: InfoBoxBuilder}});
   handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
   handler.fitMapToBounds();
   handler.getMap().setZoom(9);
  });
```

with:

```
:javascript
  var handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { builders: { Marker: InfoBoxBuilder} });
  handler.buildMap({ internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    var markers = handler.addMarkers(#{raw @hash.to_json});
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
    handler.getMap().setZoom(9);
  });
```

And `class InfoBoxBuilder` should be `class @InfoBoxBuilder` to be accessible on `window` object

Basically in the gem's doc the map creation is defined in the same file as the `InfoBoxBuilder` class. You're not doing this: you create the handler in your window.

Comment: It's working! Thank you very very much apneadiving - you are awesome.